# Streambuilder did not update Flutter

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

**STREAMBUILDER**
Did not update.
I already tried to work with initState.

On another page the data changes and when you go back to this HOMEPAGE the Streambuilder did not update.
I would be really happy, when you can give me an advice.

I think thats right to use a stateful widget isn't it.
........................................................................................................................................................................skldladlkjsdlkjslkdjsdklsdjlkasjdlajdljasldjjlkadjaskdjlkasjdlkjasdjlsajdlaskjdasdlkasjkdasjkdlkasjdskajdlsajdlsajdlkasjlkJLADJLKASJDJalksjjfaskldjfkdfjdslkfjlksdafjlködsfjdjflkdsjfjljfldskjfldskflksfljsdfj

```
class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
@override
HomepageState createState() => _HomepageState();
}

class _HomepageState extends State<Homepage> {
UserLevelStandGrossKlein lus = UserLevelStandGrossKlein(); 
SharedPreferences prefs;
UserLevelStand usl = UserLevelStand();
    
  String name = 'Tom';
  @override
 void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  void dispose() {
    lus.startWork();
    usl.startWork();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    setState(() {
           lus.startWork();
     usl.startWork();
    });

    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: SafeArea(
                  child: Column(
    
    children: [
      Row(children: [

Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 60, 0, 0),
  child: RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25,
        color: Colors.black
      ),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'Guten Tag,', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
      TextSpan(text:'\n'+ name, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
    ],
  ),
  ),    ),
      Spacer(),
      GestureDetector(
        onTap: (){
              Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Profil()));
            },
              child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 60, 40, 0),
          child: Image.asset("assets/pic.jpg",
          width: 80,),
        ),
      )
    ]

    ),
    StreamBuilder(
                              initialData:User(1, 'Lädt'),
                              stream: usl.stream(),
                              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapchot){
                                  

                               User lus = snapchot.data;
                               String stand2 = lus.userD <=25 ? 'Beginner': 'Fortgeschritten';
            
                               return
                               Padding(
                                 padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30, 0, 0, 0),
                                 child: Stack(
                                   alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                   children: [Container(
                                     height: 6,
                                     width: 150,
                                     decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.grey,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9)),
                                   Container(color: Colors.black,),
                                   AnimatedContainer(
                                     duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
                                     width: lus.userD, 
                                     height: 6,
                                     decoration: 
                                     BoxDecoration(
                                     color: Colors.blue,
                                     borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(9)))
)],
                                 ),
                               );
    }
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code of the `stream()` method defined in the `UserLevelStand` class

Comment: Do not call `setState` directly from your `build` method. `setState` calls `build`, so if you call `setState`  every time you build... well, you can see how that's going to be a nasty loop.